# rethinkdb install on centOS

Tags: centos, rethinkdb

When I install the RethinkDB on CentOS 6.5, I have en error on `scl enable devtoolset-2 -- ./configure --dynamic jemalloc --allow-fetch` stage, reporting that:

> Unable to open /etc/scl/prefixes/--!.

Is there someone else fit this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That error could be caused by a badly sconfigured or broken `scl`.

The recommended way of installing RethinkDB on Centos 6 is using the official packages:

- https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/centos/
- http://download.rethinkdb.com/centos/6/